# Track GPS Route accurately Android

Tags: android, xamarin, gps, locationmanager, fusedlocationproviderapi

I am writting an application to tracks users real time location and show it on map. However the results I am seeing are not satisfactory. When I compare my app with others present on play store the difference is a lot.

Here are the things which I have tried so far: (Just in case I am using Xamarin to build this application)

I have earlier used Fused Location Api, this gave too much of deviation from users current location. 
So, I tried with Location Manager using only GPS_Provider. Using this the accuracy increased a lot but still not perfect.

Below is my code using location manager:

```
protected void CreateLocationRequest() {
            if (locMgr.AllProviders.Contains (LocationManager.GpsProvider) && locMgr.IsProviderEnabled (LocationManager.GpsProvider)) {
                locMgr.RequestLocationUpdates (LocationManager.GpsProvider, 3000, 2, this);
            } 
        }

public void OnLocationChanged (Location location)
        {
            Console.WriteLine ("OnLocationChanged");
            if(location != null && location.Accuracy <= 20){
                drawPath (location);
            }
        }
```

Below is the screen shot of my application:

[image]

Below is the screenshot of an app from playstore

[image]

Comment: Did you record both tracks with the same device?

Comment: @greenapps yes tracked with same device

Comment: 'Below is my code using location manager:'. But you do not use 'location' so what are you doing with it? Calculating distances is irrelevant i think.

Comment: @greenapps i am basically caculating the distance and drawing the polyline. Just the normal stuff

Comment: Why are you calculating a distance? Ok i can imagine why. But we are not interested in distance i think. You better show us how you take the lat,lon from location and how you use that to plot the points.

Comment: @greenapps I am adding the polyline as it is. I am not doing any extra checks on location obtained. Except for checking its accuracy

Comment: From the screenshot i didn't observed much difference in accuracy , in ur screen it shown more curved may be because you enabled the Polyline attributre Geodesic.